# How do I create an msixbundle for a UWP project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp, msix, appxmanifest

I have two xamarin forms projects that currently only utilize the UWP platform. One creates msixbundles when publishing and the other creates appxbundles when publishing. I can't seem to find any key difference between the Package.appxmanifest or the uwp project files that would cause this. I would like to make them both produce msixbundles. Does anyone know the key to creating msixbundles vs appxbundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps targeting Windows 1809 and newer are automatically packaged  bundled as **msix/msixbundle**. And here is official [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#universal3).

> We added support for creating .MSIX packages for both the Universal
> Windows Platform projects, as well as in the Windows Application
> Packaging Project template. To create an .MSIX package, the minimum
> version of your application must be the latest Windows 10 SDK (build
> 17763).